# How to extract subexpressions in maxima?

Tags: lisp, symbolic-math, maxima

Let's assume some maxima function gave me a fraction as result. For example

```
(%o1)     bla / blubb
```

where bla and blubb are again more complicated expressions.

Now I want to process numerator and denominator separately. How can I extract them to separate variables?

I know `bla/blubb` is internally represented as a list in lisp, so I could do

```
:lisp (setq $oneofthem (nth 2 $%o1));
```

to get the lisp representation of numerator or denominator. However, I feel the maxima and lisp representation differ in commutation, so I'm not sure in advance if the maxima variable `oneofthem` contains the first or second factor (either `bla` or `(mtimes blubb -1)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main functions are [part](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_6.html#IDX195) and [inpart](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_6.html#IDX173). See also
[substinpart](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_6.html#IDX207), [pickapart](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_6.html#IDX198), [reveal](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_6.html#IDX202).